# Creating a new column and assigning values if any one of the row within a group contains a certain value

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to assign values to a new column for each group in group by based on : if any one of the rows in a group contains a specific value, then new column values for that group should be a certain value.

So far i've tried using np.where and pandas dataframe any() and apply it to group by. This has worked for a very small dataset. My original dataset contains about 1.8 Million records and the method I've tried is too slow, it never runs to completion on the original dataset. So Wondering if there is an effective way to achieve this.

For example, If I have a dataframe with columns A,B & C

```py
     A      B   C
0   alpha   m   t
1   beta    n   r
2   cosine  q   f
3   alpha   m   t
4   beta    m   t
5   alpha   n   r
6   cosine  q   f
```

For the groups for B & C, create a new column 'D' whose values are based on 'A'. In a group, if any one of the row of column A has beta, the column 'D' (all rows of D) for that group should be beta. If none of the rows in a group contain beta, next hierarchy is cosine i.e., if any of the row of column A in that group has cosine then all rows of column D of that group should be cosine.

The method I've tried so far:

```py
def test(dft):
    dft['D']=np.where(dft[dft['A']=='beta'].any(),'beta',np.where(dft[dft['A']=='cosine'].any(),'cosine',np.where(dft[dft['A']=='alpha'].any(),'alpha',dft['A'])))
    return dft['D']
```

```py
dft2=dft.groupby(['B','C']).apply(test)
dft2=dft2.reset_index()
```

Result I get is:

```
    B   C   level_2    D
0   m   t   0         beta
1   m   t   3         beta
2   m   t   4         beta
3   n   r   1         beta
4   n   r   5         beta
5   q   f   2         cosine
6   q   f   6         cosine
```

Expected result should look like:

```
     A      B   C          D
0   alpha   m   t        beta
1   beta    n   r        beta
2   cosine  q   f        cosine
3   alpha   m   t        beta
4   beta    m   t        beta
5   alpha   n   r        beta
6   cosine  q   f        cosine
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC using `Categorical` convert your columns A , then do `groupby` `transform`

```
df.A=pd.Categorical(df.A,categories=['alpha','cosine','beta'],ordered=True)
df.groupby(['B','C']).A.transform('max')
Out[1200]: 
0      beta
1      beta
2    cosine
3      beta
4      beta
5      beta
6    cosine
Name: A, dtype: object
df['D']=df.groupby(['B','C']).A.transform('max')
```

Comment: Very clever (-:

Comment: Very clever Indeed! Thanks Much! @Wen-Ben

Answer (score 1):

#### Numpy

I got it in my head to use Numpy.  This is mostly for my benefit but I thought I'd share if anyone else was interested.

```
# This will assign a factorized version of the combination of `df.B` and `df.C`
# `i` will be the integer factor values
# `u` will have the unique tuples that are the combinations themselves
i, u = pd.factorize([*zip(df.B, df.C)])

# `order` acts as both the labels and the priority ordering
order = np.array(['beta', 'cosine', 'alpha'])
# use Numpy broadcasting to see get a boolean version of one-hot encoded values
conds = df.A.values == order[:, None]

# create a new array that has the same number of rows as the number of unique
# combinations of `'B'` and `'C'`... or `len(u)` and the number of columns equal
# to the number of items in `order`
out = np.zeros((len(u), len(order)), bool)

j = np.tile(i, len(u))
k = np.arange(len(u)).repeat(len(i))

# Surgically place cumulative or evaluations into the `out` array
np.logical_or.at(out, (k, j), conds.ravel())

df.assign(D=np.select(out, order)[i])

        A  B  C       D
0   alpha  m  t    beta
1    beta  n  r    beta
2  cosine  q  f  cosine
3   alpha  m  t    beta
4    beta  m  t    beta
5   alpha  n  r    beta
6  cosine  q  f  cosine
```